# Stylizing checkbox via CSS? How does Shopify do it?

Tags: css

Check out the [Shopify login page](https://www.shopify.com/login) and note the checkbox (it's green). I've been inspecting away but can't figure out how they're doing this. I did figure out the real checkbox is hidden behind this one (via `float: left`). But this thing is not an image. No idea how they pulled that off. Any CSS geniuses care to take a look?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the "Remember me" checkbox, what is your question? There is nothing magic about that checkbox (it seems a perfectly normal white, inline SVG with a green background, see 
`.marketing-checkbox:checked + label::before` and `.marketing-checkbox:checked + label::after` respectively).

Comment: It is likely a replacement element, JS-based. This is because OS-styling of replaced elements (like inputs) are set in stone and notoriously hard to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it , they reduce the width and height of the real checkbox and used `label:before` pseudo element instead:

here is the code they used to create their custom checkbox :

```
.marketing-checkbox-label:before, .marketing-radio-label:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 150ms ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 150ms ease;
   transition: border-color 150ms ease;
}
```